# AngularJs populate an accordion list

Tags: angularjs, accordion

I want to construct an accordion list of '***Exercises***'. I get following response from my backend which is basically a list of exercise objects having multiple properties.

```
[{
    "exercise_name": "Best Stretch",
    "intensity_level": 6,
    "description": "Test"
}, {
    "exercise_name": "Butterfly reverse",
    "intensity_level": 1,
    "description": "Test"
},{
    "exercise_name": "Squat",
    "intensity_level": 1,
    "description": "Test"
}]
```

My accordion list should look something like:

- Exercises for Today

  - Best Stretch
  - Butterfly reverse
  - Squat
  - and so on..

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: With this backend data in hand how can I construct my accordion list in the above format i.e iterating over multiple objects and fetching exercise_name to construct the list?

Comment: FYI, you have a syntax issue around the `intensity` property of the first object, which will derail anything that tries to use it.

Comment: Yes I just manually edited it, there were many other fields and it was getting too large, so just deleted few to make it simpler. I will create a plnkr in sometime and post it

Answer (score 0):

The key for you is to read up on the [`ng-repeat` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). This will allow you to loop the items in your data set and output them in the form that the accordion control requires. Armed with this information you should try making it work and if you are still having difficulty then you can post a more relevant question showing what you have tried and describing exactly what's not working.